# Why does calling the DOM history API cause cordova to fail to load images in Android app?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, dom

I'm using cordova to create an android app from a SPA web app made without any frameworks, but none of the image tags work in android. All of them are unable to get the source attribute; however, the same path will work if it's used in css as the value for the URL attribute. So it seems the paths are correct. These images are stored locally in the www/img folder.

Since this is a SPA app, I'm using the HTML5 history api to handle the back button functionality in the app. I found that the image tags will work fine until i make a call to the history API, but afterwards the image tags will not work.

Calls to history API:

```
function renderPage(route, back) {
  if (!back) {
    window.history.pushState({}, route, window.location.origin + route);
  }

window.onpopstate = () => {
  renderPage(window.location.pathname, true);
};
```

Disabling the above code snippets will result in the image tags working properly. This issue does not occur in the browser.

Comment: the paths to your images are relative or absolute?

Comment: The paths are relative

Comment: you need absolute paths, the route is changing so your image paths should change

Comment: That seemed to do the trick, using the cordova file plugin.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using absolute paths and getting the root with the cordova file plugin seems to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

> **Think about the security of your application!**
>
> So fullquote following - Original post over here As far as i
>   understood the whole ATS (App Transport Security - iOS 9) thing, the
>   recommended method from area28 should not be the one you're using
>   inside an application.
>
> ```
> <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> 
> <dict> 
>     <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
> </dict>
> ```
>
> **This will allow all external requests to every domain what is definitively not the way you should use it**. In my opinion you should
>   define a new  inside your info.plist and add this code to it (to
>   edit the info.plist you can just use a normal text editor like sublime
>   text etc.):
>
> ```
> <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
>     <dict>
>         <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
>         <dict>
>             <key>domain.tld</key>
>             <dict>
>                 <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
>                 <true/>
>                 <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
>                 <true/>
>                 <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
>                 <string>TLSv1.1</string>
>             </dict>
>         </dict>
>     </dict>
> ```
>
> This will only allow requests to the domain you specified. The
>   described way is the one which apple [introduced on the WWDC 2015](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/711/).
>   As you can see on the screenshot, it's the way apple want the users to
>   use it.
>
> If you haven't specified anything, you'll get
>
> Failed to load webpage with error: The resource could not be loaded
>   because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure
>   connection.
>
> So, change it and the error is gone away.
>
> [image]